# Solid border for CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a CALayer for which I need to add a shadow. 
I have tried

```
myLayer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
myLayer.shadowOpacity = 1;
myLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
myLayer.shadowRadius = 1;
```

This only gives me a blurred shadow.
How can I get a solid one?

Comment: I think you should try [myLayer setBorderWidth:1]; [myLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

Comment: Nope, tried it already. Doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try with different Border Color ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

change the shadowOffset value and check
change the shadow color to other than white

```
myLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(X,X);
```

(X = any value that suits to your requirement)

e.g.

```
myLayer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,2);
```

Comment: this moves the shadow. It doesnt make it solid.